Convert Binary search tree to max heap does not work property while insert each node to root
I need to convert binary search tree to max heap in java. As I did like this,
public static void inOrderTraversal(Node node, Vector<Node> vec)
{
    if(node == null)
    {
        return ;
    }
    //first travel in left
    
    inOrderTraversal(node.left, vec);
    vec.add(node);
    
    inOrderTraversal(node.right, vec);
}


public static void createHeap()
{
    Vector<Node> vec = new Vector<>();
    index = -1;
    inOrderTraversal(rootTree, vec);
    
    
    System.out.println("in order traversal");
    for(int l=0; l< vec.size(); l++)
    {
        System.out.print(vec.get(l).word +"===>"+ vec.get(l).count + ",");
        
    }
    System.out.println();
    heapifying(rootTree,vec);

    System.out.println("post order traversal");
    postOrderTraversal(rootTree,vec);
Vector<Node> heapVec = new Vector<>();
        for(int l=0; l< heapVec.size(); l++)
        {
            System.out.print(heapVec.get(l).word +"===>"+ heapVec.get(l).count + ",");
        
    }
}

public static void heapifying(Node node, Vector<Node> vec)
{
    if(node == null)
    {
        return ;
    }
    
    heapifying(node.left, vec);
    
    heapifying(node.right, vec);
    index = index+1;
    node = vec.get(index);
}

public static void postOrderTraversal(Node root,Vector<Node> vec)
{
    if(root == null)
    {
        return ;
    }
    vec.add(root);
    postOrderTraversal(root.left, vec);
    
    postOrderTraversal(root.right, vec);
    
    
}

public Node insertNodeToTree(Node root, int count, String word)
{
    if(root == null)
    {
        return root = new Node(word,count);
    }
    
    //go to 
    if(root.count < count)
    {
        root.right = insertNodeToTree(root.right, count, word);
    }
    
    else {
        root.left = insertNodeToTree(root.left, count, word);
    }
    
    return root;
}

In main method,
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BinartSearchTree bst = new BinartSearchTree();
    
    
    rootTree = bst.insertNodeToTree(rootTree, 8, "john");
    rootTree = bst.insertNodeToTree(rootTree, 12, "juhirdeen");
    rootTree = bst.insertNodeToTree(rootTree, 10, "feroz");
    rootTree = bst.insertNodeToTree(rootTree, 11, "rush");
    rootTree = bst.insertNodeToTree(rootTree, 7, "nisham");
    rootTree = bst.insertNodeToTree(rootTree, 14, "nisham");
    rootTree = bst.insertNodeToTree(rootTree, 17, "nisham");
    rootTree = bst.insertNodeToTree(rootTree, 15, "nisham");
    
    createHeap();
    
}

I follow up https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-bst-to-max-heap/ this article and created my own BST. Everything fine.  I could not figure out what wrong with first insertNodeToTree method calling way,
As I read article the way BST created is little different than my

"But I didn't return the root of max heap.": where do you call heapifying? Also, you seem to compare pieces of code that do not create the same variables, nor the same nodes. Neither calls heapifying. With which code can we reproduce the issue?

Also, this heapifying function is making a useless assignment to node. Nor does it populate your vec. It doesn't do anything useful.

first I put all nodes in BST to inorder manner into an vector(or else we can use int array) So we have the sorted nodes in vector. then I pass vector into the heapifying(Node node, Vector vec) in this method, In this method I do postOrder Traversal from BST root. And copy vector node to each node by index

What is node, wat is vec? Not initialised? What you expect from that call? Can you provide the code you tested with?

I follow up with https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-bst-to-max-heap/ this. My problem is when I create the BST tree with insertNodeToTree(Node root, int count, String word) method. it is not working. getNode(int data) method is working properly

Your code doesn't compile. Node, index, rootTree, ... and many other names are not defined.
